# How to update Array of objects in React js using state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to update value of one object only but updating value of one Object, Updates the value for all objects.

```
let default = {
    name: '',
    age: ''
}
this.state = {
    values: Array(2).fill(default)
}

updateName (event) {
    let index = event.target.id,
    values = this.state.values;

    values[index].name = event.target.value;

    this.setState ({
        values: values
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please be as clear as possible about what you want to do, what you see happening instead, and why that's surprising. Right now, it's not clear. Where possible, include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Objects are copied using reference. So both the values in array will point to same object. Instead use inline object or use `Object.assign({}, defaultState)`. `default` is not a good variable name. Try being a bit specific

Answer (score 1):

There are four significant problems in that code.

1. You're using the **same** object for all entries in your array. If you want to have different objects, you have to create multiple copies of the default.
2. You're calling `setState` incorrectly. Any time you're setting state based on existing state (and you're setting `values` based, indirectly, on `this.state.values`), you **must** use the function callback version of `setState`. More: [*State Updates May Be Asynchronous*](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)
3. You can't directly modify the object held in `this.state.values`; instead, you must make a *copy* of the object and modify that. More: [*Do Not Modify State Directly*](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)
4. `default` is a [keyword](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-keywords), you can't use it as an identifier. Let's use `defaultValue` instead.

Here's one way you can address all four (see comments):

```
// #4 - `default` is a keyword
let defaultValue = {
    name: '',
    age: ''
};
this.state = {
    // #1 - copy default, don't use it directly
    values: [
        Object.assign({}, defaultValue),
        Object.assign({}, defaultValue),
    ] // <=== Side note - no ; here!
};

// ....

updateName(event) {
    // Grab the name for later use
    const name = event.target.value;
    // Grab the index -- I __don't__ recommend using indexed updates like this;
    // instead, use an object property you can search for in the array in case
    // the order changes (but I haven't done that in this code).
    const index = event.target.id;
    // #2 - state updates working from current state MUST use
    // the function callback version of setState
    this.setState(prevState => {
        // #3 - don't modify state directly - copy the array...
        const values = prevState.values.slice();

        // ...and the object, doing the update; again, I wouldn't use an index from
        // the `id` property here, I'd find it in the `values` array wherever it
        // is _now_ instead (it may have moved).
        values[index] = {...values[index], name};

        return {values};
    });
}
```

Note that this line in the above:

```
values[index] = {...values[index], name};
```

...uses [property spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) added in ES2018 (and [shorthand property syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), just `name` instead of `name: name`).

Comment: @Rajesh: `slice` just copies *the array*, the objects in the array are still shared with the state. We have to copy the object, too, prior to modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function with combination of the [object spread syntax (stage 4)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread):

Note that i changed the name of the `default` object to `obj`.
`default`  is a [reserved key word in javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

```
let obj = {
    name: '',
    age: ''
}
this.state = {
    values: Array(2).fill(obj)
}

updateName(event){
    const {id, value} = event.target;  
    this.setState(prev => {
    const {values} = prev;

    const nextState = values.map((o,idx) => {
        if(idx !== id)
        return o; // not our object, return as is

      return{
          ...o,
          name: value;
        }
    });

      return{
        values: nextState
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Good catch on `default`. It's not just reserved, [it's a keyword](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-keywords).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy and safe way to achieve that through the following:

```
this.setState({
  values: [ newObject, ...this.state.values],
});
```

this will create an instance of the state and change the value of an existing object with new object.